# How to work with dictionary of array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, lodash

All my data are tabular data, for storage/transfer efficiency, I stored them as dictionary of arrays.

```
// take the following tabular data for e.g.
// | somecol1 | somecol2 | somecol3 |
// | c1r1     | c2r1     | c3r1     |
// | c1r2     | c2r2     | c3r2     |
// 
// instead of 
[ {somecol1:c1r1, somecol2:c2r1, somecol3:c3r1 ....}, ... ]  // Scheme I
// I got 
{ somecol1:[c1r1, c1r2, c1r3...], somecol2:[c2r1, ...]... }  // Scheme II
```

Currently I use the latter scheme, it avoid redundancy. I could get thousands of records easily and quickly. But in the meanwhile, It made basic things not as handy as array of objects for processing. I don't want to transform them back to array of objects when processing.

I haven't used JavaScript for quite some time. I am not quite familiar with lodash. 
I find working with these object not handy at all. e.g. to filter for rows where `col1 = val1` and `col2 = val2`

I do `_filter( dict_of_array, [{col1:val1}, {col2:val2}])`, where `_filter` is my user function like below.

```
// keypairs = [{key1:key_value1}, ...] 
function _filter( dict, kpairs ) { 
var dict_keys = _.keys(dict);
var bitmask = _.map(Array(dict[dict_keys[0]].length),function(){return true});
_.each(kpairs,function(kpair){
    _.each(kpair,function(kval, key){
        _.each(dict[key], function(item, idx){
            bitmask[idx] = bitmask[idx] && (item == kval);
        })
    });
});
var result = {};
_.each(dict_keys, function(k){ result[k] = []; });
_.each(bitmask, function(v, idx){
    _.each(dict_keys, function(k){
        if(bitmask[idx]) result[k].push(dict[k][idx]); 
    });
})
return result;
}
```

compared to working with array of objects:

```
_.filter(scheme1, ['col1', 'val1', 'col2', 'val2'] )
```

It's more complicated and multi-columne sorting is worse. The way I use lodash is not saving much time.

There must be a more efficient way to filter/sort/pop records from this type of objects (without transforming them into array of objects). I just don't know.

If lodash doesn't fit. I assume there should be other common lib to work with them?

I am thinking alasql.js, but that's SQL oriented. Some more common ways in JavaScript e.g. using jQuery etc, would be more helpful.

Comment: What should happen to `val2`, `val3`, which are also associated with `col1`?

Comment: could you please give an example of the input and the output you're expecting? I got lost

Comment: If you haven't written JS in a while, you might be interested to learn more about modern JS.  The lodash functions you are using are now regular JS.  https://github.com/you-dont-need/You-Dont-Need-Lodash-Underscore

Comment: There's a reason there are more libraries and built-in methods for working with arrays of objects than there are for working with objects of arrays; that's how the problem domain is normally modeled. Logically, you have a number of things, each of which have properties with values -- you don't have one thing with properties that have many values. I understand the efficiency aspect, but seeing the code you have there, you've likely hit the point where the amount of code necessary to deal with the "efficient" storage method is outweighing the amount of storage you save.

Comment: Hi I updated the post. Hopefully it's clear now. @HereticMonkey, that's a exact description of my situation now :-). I am caching a lot of db data in the browser to create a semi offline mode. It cut the delays and reduced queries. But it is getting more complicated. I hope I can find a utility lib in js to make it easier.

Comment: If you're caching db data, and you want to perform fast db actions on that data, you might want to use [indexeddb](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API) to store it.